# Delete duplicate userIds on a DocuSign user - possible

Tags: docusignapi

and sorry for potentially flogging the dead horse...

We're in the process of renewing our DocuSign implementation and I guess we are not alone experiencing user duplication like this:
[DS user duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZhCl.png)

I guess I look for verification that each of these userIds are considered as a unique user within DocuSign, and as such they cannot be truly deleted, only closed. So, deal with it and move on, or is there something I have missed out on?

Thanks, Mads

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that a user's membership in an account can be closed but not deleted.

Are the additional closed memberships causing you any API issues?

If so, contact DocuSign developer support.

Comment: No, at least not operational issues. I think for reactivations, I'll have to work out a logic that picks the right, closed account and tell the business to adhere to that. Picking the duplicate with the newest "membership_created_on" date should work out.